# How to use the aframe daydream trackpad controls?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to use the daydream trackpad in aframe. In particular I need events that let me see it as a touchpad. In other words I need touchstart, touchmove, and touchend events or equivalent.

The [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/daydream-controls.html) only list these events

```
trackpadchanged     Trackpad changed.
trackpaddown        Trackpad pressed.
trackpadup          Trackpad released.
trackpadtouchstart  Trackpad touched.
trackpadtouchend    Trackpad not touched.
```

Notice there is no `trackpadmove` or `trackpadtouchmove`. I tried adding an event to `trackpadchanged` but it's not a touchmove like event.

If I want to say "scroll through something" I need values as the user moves their finger across the pad.

I tried printing out all of those events

```
const dd = this.el.querySelector('#daydream-controls');
[
  'trackpadchanged',
  'trackpaddown',
  'trackpadup',
  'trackpadtouchstart',
  'trackpadtouchend',
].forEach((event) => {
  dd.addEventListener(event, (e) => {
    console.log(event, e);
  });
});
```

But I don't see any events as I drag my finger on the pad. I only see `trackpadtouchstart` followed by `trackpadchanged` when I touch the pad and then I see `trackpadtouchend` followed by `trakpadchanged` when I release.

Is there some other event I should be looking for or some other way to read when the user moves their finger across the pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `axismove` event provided by underlying `tracked-controls`.

See also: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-thumb-controls-component

Comment: Thanks!  It's strange. I went back to my code and I had added all the events from `tracked-controls` right after posting my question but for some reason it didn't work (not sure why). Today it worked, not sure what changed but yay!